# Doppler spectral power density

Tags: power, spectrum

In layman terms, why doppler spectral power density has U shape?

Does this mean that frequency components with maximum doppler shift have maximum power?

I am confused with the interpretation of the doppler spectral power density U-shaped graph, for example the one at https://blog.taitradio.com/2015/09/23/9-channel-concepts-every-system-designer-needs-to-understand/.

Additionally, I found this source: https://www.sharetechnote.com/html/Handbook_LTE_Fading.html. Does this mean that the U-shaped graph actually depicts probability density of frequency shifts and has nothing to do with the power/amplitude?

Comment: Please add some context to your question so we can answer it.  What is the source of the signal being analyzed?

Comment: "In layman's terms": um, no, a layman would need a couple of hours of explanation what a Doppler spectrum is. You'll need to explain what you *don't* understand yourself. As is, this question prompts us to write a complete introdcution to signals and systems, to channels and to spectral estimation. That's far too broad for a single answer. Please narrow down your question.

Comment: I am confused with the interpretation of the doppler spectral power density U-shaped graph, for example the one at https://blog.taitradio.com/2015/09/23/9-channel-concepts-every-system-designer-needs-to-understand/.

Comment: Put that taitradio context in your question.

Comment: @Neil_UK OK, I did.

Comment: **Does this mean that the U-shaped graph actually depicts probability density of frequency shifts and has nothing to do with the power/amplitude?** Yes, spot on!

Comment: @Neil_UK Why it's then called power spectral density?

Comment: it's not the power of the RF signal, it's the power of the probability

Comment: @Neil_UK By saying "power of probability" you mean probability of obtaining a given frequency shift?

Comment: Yes. The context is communication engineering, where the things that get measured are mean error rates. Power is fundamental to doing those sorts of calculations, you see things like Eb/N0 all over the place. Powers add nicely, especially when it's co-channels and noise and the like. When you try to figure out how fading affects the link, it's natural to talk in terms of 'power', an amplitude squared, even if it doesn't mean 'watts'. You might need to get knee-deep into doing those calculations if you want to understand it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this probably belongs in physics.